# Java/Scala Create test Directory for testing write failures

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, file, io

I am unit testing I/O code roughly of the following form. I want to test that the fallback logic works if the write fails initially. How can I create a file path such that it will fail the initial write?

```
def myMethod(dirPath: String): File = {
  val tempFile = File.createTempFile(PREFIX, ".zip", new File(dirPath))
  // write to tempfile
  tempFile
}

try {
  myMethod(DIR_PATH)
} catch {
  // some fallback logic
  if (ALT_PATH != null) {
    myMethod(ALT_PATH)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a name certain to be illegal, like `"slashes/\non-printables\/weird unicodes\/colons for windows"`. You could also create a file and then try to recreate it in the test, assuming the second attempt will fail, etc. Or maybe a strange relative path `../../../../../../../../../../somefile` which will run into permission issues (assuming you don't run your tests as root, etc.

Comment: @ernest_k looking for a commonly used method for doing such tests, trying to make as little assumptions about the test environments as possible